# Download Only A Part of a JPG with HTTP request

Tags: http, jpeg

With the HTTP header `Range` clients can request only a certain range of bytes from a server.

```
GET myfile.jpg HTTP/1.1
"http://myhost"
Range=bytes=1000-1200
```

If the server supports this response feature and maybe even shows that by a `Accept-Range` header, the above request will return only the 200 bytes from byte 1000 onwards.

Is it possible to get usable parts from an JPG image with this method? Say the actual JPG measures 800x1197 pixels. What would have to be done in order to request only a sub image between the pixels 200x200 and 400x400?

To me it looks like it's only possible receive horizontally cut slices of the image. But this would already be better than getting the full image file. So in the example above I'd say one could try to download: the slice from 200 (y-axis) to 400 (y-axis) and then crop the result on the client side accordingly.

Assume we already know the content-length of the file as well as its actual image size, which may have been determined by a preceding HTTP request:

content length in bytes: 88073
jpg size: 800x1197

Which byte range would I have to request for this image? I assume that JPG has some meta data, which has to be taken in account as well. Or does the compression of jpg render this attempt impossible? It would be ok if the final cut out does not contain any metadata from the original.

But still it might be necessary to have an initial request, which takes some bytes from the beginning hoping to fetch the metadata. and based on this the actual byte range might be determined.

Would be very nice if someone could give me a hint how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPEG encodes compressed data in one or more scans. The scans do not indicate their length. You have to actually decode to get to the end of the scan. The scans span the entire image.

If the JPEG stream is progressively encoded you can read the stream blocks at at a time, decode the scans, update the output image, and get successively refined views of the image.

Comment: Ok, I see. This is very clarifying. I came to the conclusion that it is not possible to what I tried to with JPG. With PNG i think it would work but JPEG works as you describe it.