# Downloading an image in low quality

Tags: image, flutter, image-processing

I was wondering how to download an image from flutter from a given url, in low quality so it consumes less data and is loaded faster.
For example the following code

```
Image.network(
'https://images3.alphacoders.com/823/thumb-1920-82317.jpg',
)
```

will download and display a 500kb image, but i want to display it in a **small area**, so I want to download a smaller version the image ( maybe only 50 kb ) and then display it. Is there any work around for it.
There are some sites like https://imgproxy.net/ that can do it on the fly, but how to do it within the app.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that easy nor reliable. In the majority of bitmap file formats you have to download the whole photo to then decode it. Only after decoding it you can perform some operations on it like resizing the photo or compressing it, which isn't what you want.

There are few bitmap types out there that support progressive loading, like JPG with progressive encoding (see [Download Only A Part of a JPG with HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41664589/3158312)). I remember something that there was this new file format with very minimal support of browsers which supported progressive loading among other features. But you would have to program support for it in Dart by yourself.

The best way to achieve what you need is to actually use some image proxy service (like [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations) or the one you provided) or self-host one of the open-source ones (like [willnoris/imageproxy](https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy)).

Tl;dr no.